# Will my partisions on my hard drive be removed if I choose "Erase disk"?

Tags: partitioning

I am using windows 7 with 3 partitions on my hard drive.
Now i want to install ubuntu by completely removing windows and other files.
I even don't want the partitions.
Will "Erase disk" remove the partitions also or it will keep the partitions?
Please give the solution to my problem.

Comment: There is no problem, it will erase disk by erasing the partition table, thus when new partition table is created it'll be empty with no partitions. The disk is a level higher than partition table, partition table is a level higher than partitions...

Answer (score 2):

- **Yes, "Erase disk" will remove the partitions and file systems.**

  If I understand correctly, this is what you want.

---

- But if, instead of installing Ubuntu you were to sell the computer, then "Erase disk" is not enough.

  There are recovery tools, that can recover a fair part of the raw data from the memory cells and re-create files. So you should overwrite the whole drive or better, re-arrange the mapping between logical and physical memory locations. This remapping can be done with `hdparm`, and is more advanced.

Answer (score 1):

"Erase disk" will do *exactly what it promises*. It will delete all partitions and all data within them.

Answer (score 1):

When you select "Erase Disk" in the Ubuntu installer, it'll delete ***everything.*** Ubuntu will repartition the disk to install Ubuntu.